# Javascript new Date() returns completely different date

Tags: javascript, datetime

For timestamp **1602742707.662** it is giving following date instead of *Thursday, 15 October 2020 11:48:27.662 GMT+05:30*

```js
var date = new Date(1602742707.662);
Mon Jan 19 1970 18:42:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

And for today's date it is giving correct value

```js
var today = new Date();
Thu Oct 15 2020 11:48:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
At first I am passing timestamp in milliseconds but it is returning Invalid Date

```js
var date = new Date(1602742707662);
console.log(date);
```

So I am dividing the timestamp by 1000 and passing it

Comment: timestamps in javascript are in milliseconds - try `new Date(1602742707.662 * 1000)` i.e. `new Date(1602742707662)` or read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: @JaromandaX when I am using timestamp in milliseconds it is returning Invalid date

Comment: no it isn't returning an invalid date ... `new Date(1602742707662);` will give `2020-10-15T06:18:27.662Z` ... which is `Thursday, 15 October 2020 11:48:27.662 GMT+05:30` - perhaps you're doing something wrong - are you multiplying `1602742707.662`  by 1e7? because that's how much you have to multiply it to get an invalid date ... try multiplying by 1e3 instead

Comment: I've turned your final code into an executable snippet ... does it output invalid date? (hint: no, it does not)

Comment: I am doing the same thing in the code and logging it. It is giving Invalid Date

Comment: what if you run the snippet in your question? what do you get? - i.e click on run code snippet

Comment: "2020-10-15T06:18:27.662Z" This is the output I am getting

Comment: see, it works as expected - you must be doing something wrong in your real code

Answer (score 3):

You're passing in seconds since the Unix Epoch into the [date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date). The date constructor expects milliseconds since the Unix Epoch. In order to get the correct date, you can do the following:

```
var date = new Date(1602742707.662 * 1000);
```

Comment: At first I was passing milliseconds but it is returning **Invalid Date**. So I am passing in seconds

Comment: you must be doing something else wrong in your real code then @godspeed

Comment: @godspeed If you just pass in `new Date(1602742707662)`, you should not be getting an invalid date. Just putting this into the DevTools console, this gives "Thu Oct 15 2020 01:18:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)" (or whatever the equivalent time is for your timezone).